# Javascript decorators

Tags: javascript, decorator

I am building my own node.js application now, and I have a question
I want to write something like this

```
@admin
router.delete(users/:userId)....
```

The @admin means this request is only available for admin(role-management). So the question 
1. What is @something called in javascript(Decorators in python and annotations in Java)
2. Can I write my own @somethings?
Also example will be appreciated.)

Comment: 1. use express so you don't reinvent the wheel 2. JS doesn't have decorators but you can use express middleware for role management

Comment: You mean adding middleware function that will check for roles?

Comment: Decorators are available in typescript, not JavaScript.

Comment: There's a decorators proposal for JavaScript but it's not really finished yet. And I don't think that proposal would provide the functionality implied by the example in this question.

Comment: I got it guys, as JS does not have decorators I will handle that in middleware, thx)